# Python loop - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python

I am using `while` loop to execute some code:

```
while (totalIter > 0):
    totalIter = totalIter - 1
    route_data = yield Runner.execute(endpoint, endpoint.config, command, send_data)
```

Where `Runner` is imported as `from prov.runners.base import Runner`

The `yield` statement works fine for first time but on second execution of the loop, it throw below error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'execute'

indicating that `Runner` has become `None`.

I have tried following things but of no use.

```
import prov.runners.base     
while (totalIter > 0):
        totalIter = totalIter - 1
        reload(prov.runners.base.Runner)
        route_data = yield prov.runners.base.Runner.execute(endpoint, endpoint.config, command, send_data)
```

which gives error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'runners'

indicating `prov` is `None` on second execution.

Tried reloading `Runner` only, but python gives error that `reload expects module as argument.`

Is this problem at all related to loading of module or something else?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but is there any particular reason you're iterating with a while loop, and decrementing manually, instead of doing `for _ in range(totalIter):`?

Comment: what happens if you replace `route_data = yield  ...` by just `print(Runner)` ?

Comment: New to python, will change if to for loop if this one is better :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Works fine and prints `<class 'prov.runners.base.Runner'>
<class 'prov.runners.base.Runner'>` as many times as loop executes. Seems `yield` is causing the issue.

Comment: ok, then try to yield something unrelated.

Comment: How are you running your code? Does `execute` return a value or `void`?

Comment: Actually nevermind. If you're running the generator properly, value vs `void` doesn't seem to matter in terms of exceptions.

Comment: If you're trying to use `route_data` for anything, the yield won't work for you (it will always set it to `None`)

Comment: Try `x = prov.runners.base.Runner.execute(*etc*)` followed by new line `route_data = yield x`

Comment: The source/full description of `execute` could also help

Comment: I was calling some another function of same file from execute, and somehow Runner was getting unloaded. Removed that call and issue got solved.